# Swift: UIBezierPath bezierPathByReversingPath() Issues

Tags: ios, swift, uibezierpath

I am using `bezierPathByReversingPath()` trying to make an animating circle. I finally found a method that will work, but I am getting this bar across the circle that is not being "deleted".

**The Code:**

```
@IBDesignable class circle: UIView {

    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
        let center = CGPoint(x:bounds.width/2, y: bounds.height/2)

        let circlePath : UIBezierPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center, radius:
            CGFloat(250), startAngle: CGFloat(0), endAngle: CGFloat(360), clockwise: true)
        let circlePath2 : UIBezierPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center, radius:
            CGFloat(200), startAngle: CGFloat(0), endAngle: CGFloat(360), clockwise: true)

        circlePath.appendPath(circlePath2.bezierPathByReversingPath())
        circlePath.fill() //appendPath(circlePath.bezierPathByReversingPath())    
    }
}
```

**The Picture**

[image]

P.S. If you want an example of what I am doing, it is a win/lose animation in the iOS game "Dulp".

Comment: What is the shape that you intend to draw? How are you animating this shape?

Comment: @KennethBruno I am just intending to draw a circle and then delete the inter part of the circle with `bezierPathByReversingPath`, but the black bar appears. The animation doesn't affect anything, I just wanted to give that information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because `UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center, radius: CGFloat(250), startAngle: CGFloat(0), endAngle: CGFloat(360), clockwise: true)` takes radians, not degrees, as you specify here.

Thus, one would need to supply the arguments in radians.

I created a simple function that converts from degrees to radians; the result turned out fine.

Here is the function:

```
func degreesToRadians(degree : Int) -> CGFloat
{
    return CGFloat(degree) * CGFloat(M_PI) / 180.0
}
```

Usage:

```
let circlePath : UIBezierPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center, radius: 250.0, startAngle: self.degreesToRadians(0), endAngle:    
                                             self.degreesToRadians(360), clockwise: true)

let circlePath2 : UIBezierPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center, radius: 200.0, startAngle: self.degreesToRadians(0), endAngle:        
                                              self.degreesToRadians(360), clockwise: true)
```

Or one could create a protocol extension:

```
extension Double
{
    var degreesToRad : CGFloat
    {
        return CGFloat(self) * CGFloat(M_PI) / 180.0
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
let circlePath : UIBezierPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center, radius: 250.0, startAngle: 0.0.degreesToRad , endAngle: 360.0.degreesToRad, clockwise: true)

let circlePath2 : UIBezierPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center, radius: 200.0, startAngle: 0.0.degreesToRad, endAngle: 360.0.degreesToRad, clockwise: true)
```

Comment: I thought I was pass this stage of programming n00bery. Thanks, this is a very good answer.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the angles are in radians - not degrees. So your circles are going around 30 or so times and not ending up where they started. That's what gives you the bar.

Secondly, you can just stroke one circle instead of creating two and filling them:

```
@IBDesignable class Circle: UIView {
  override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
    let center = CGPoint(x:bounds.width/2, y: bounds.height/2)

    let circlePath : UIBezierPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center, radius:
      CGFloat(225), startAngle: CGFloat(0), endAngle: CGFloat(2*M_PI), clockwise: true)
    circlePath.lineWidth = 50
    circlePath.stroke()
  }
}
```

Comment: It ends up that radians were the only issue. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @RogueStudios Radians were one issue. Yes, you can add two circles with opposite windings as you are doing but it adds complications that are not needed. Stroking the path with a width is simpler and accomplishes what you need.

Comment: I do understand, but with the animation I am doing with the circle, that will not work. I appreciate the help though! If you want to know what I am trying to do, read the post script in my question.